# ServiceStack Client Exception Behavior (New Api)

Tags: c#, api, servicestack

Since upgrading to the latest version (3.9.24) of SS our "custom" error handling on the client side (.NET clients) has stopped working as expected. We used to rely on the "ResponseDTO" property of the WebServiceException to handle/respond to exceptions. Now that property is a type of "ServiceModel.ErrorResponse" (which is empty) and not our custom response type. When viewing the raw response in Fiddler the data is as expected, but the SS clients are not parsing/handling it the same as before. Is this design still possible in the new api? If not, what would be the proper approach? We need complete control over the presentation of the data, exceptions, and HTTP status codes.

Thanks